# how to print no underscored words

Tags: python

```
def no_underscored_words(words_string):
    '''Receives a string (word_string containing zero or 
    more comma separated words. Returns  a list of words
    in words_string that do not contain any underscore 
    character in them.'''
    result = []
    word_list = words_string.split(",")
    for word in word_list:
        if word != "_":
            result.append(word)
    return result
```

This is what i got, but failed :(

any suggestion would be appreciated

the question ask for

print(no_underscored_words('12,_init__,main'))  and expect Result should be ['12', 'main']

print(no_underscored_words('my_list,your_list')) and expect Result should be    []

Comment: I think you mean `if "_" not in word` instead of `if word != "_"`.

Comment: Is this some kind of homework?

Answer (score 1):

replace

`if word != "_":`

with

`if "_" not in word:`

Answer (score 1):

Let's define the function `no_under`.  For convenience, let's define it interactively in `ipython`:

```
In [7]:: def no_under(word_string):
  ...:     return [word for word in word_string.split(',') if not '_' in word]
  ...:
```

Two test cases demonstrate that this works as desired:

```
In [8]: no_under('12,_init__,main')
Out[8]: ['12', 'main']

In [9]: no_under('my_list,your_list')
Out[9]: []
```

#### How it works

The function contains the single command:

```
return [word for word in word_string.split(',') if not '_' in word]
```

`word_string.split(',')` converts the comma-separated `word_string` into a list of words.  Those words are included in the final list provided that the `if` clause is True.  `'_' in word` tests whether the word contains an underscore.  If it doesn't, it is included in our final list that we return.

Answer (score 0):

```
def no_underscored_words(words_string):
    '''Receives a string (word_string containing zero or 
    more comma separated words. Returns  a list of words
    in words_string that do not contain any underscore 
    character in them.'''
    result = []
    word_list = words_string.split(",")
    for word in word_list:
        if not('_' in word):
            result.append(word)
    return result

print(no_underscored_words('12,_init__,main'))
print(no_underscored_words('my_list,your_list'))
```

Output:

```
['12', 'main']
[]
```